# Auto Increment for Oracle11g by date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to create a sequence and a trigger to auto-increment the primary key on a table for every row. I want the primary key auto-increment by date like this. Example : i have date like this : `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM`. I want make the primary key auto-increment with format  : `yyyymmddxxx`.

```
Example : 20160510001, 20160510002 , 20160510003 and so on.
```

But I have no idea on how to do it.
Someone please help me.

Comment: so what happens when two rows are inserted at the exact same moment? Unlikely but possible.  Better to have a numeric sequence as primary key and then have a timestamp column with default set to current_timestamp

Comment: @kevinsky the question is how to add the date in `prefix` of the auto-increment number, so e.g in 2016/05/10 all `id` will be in format 20160510xxxxxx with `xxxxxx` is the auto-increment number

Comment: @PhamX.Bach  right now the question does not mention prefix. It says " I want the primary key auto-increment by date".  Adding a numeric suffix would prevent identical primary keys.

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when the date changes - does the numeric part start again at 1, or carry on - so would first record tomorrow be 20160511001 or 20160511004? I assume the former or you'd run out of numbers quickly if the sequence isn't cycling, but either way assumes you'll have less than 1000 rows added each day. Why do you want the date to be part of the key though? As kevinsky says, better to have separate synthetic key and date columns.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach as said by kevinsky is true. Sorry for my bad English but i want to make it works like mentioned by kevinsky.